Jetson Nano and Arduino Problem
I am developing a project with ROS on a Jetson Nano board. I connect my Arduino Mega board, which I have connected to an external PCB, to the USB ports on the Jetson board. There are also other sensors connected to the USB ports on the Jetson board. When I wake up the system via ROS, if my Arduino board is connected to the Jetson, the RVIZ does not work correctly, but when I remove it, it works correctly. After removing it, I can run it without any problems when I connect the Arduino to the Jetson board. But I did not understand why there was an error when I first worked the system and when the Arduino was connected to the Jetson. I did not receive any error messages in the terminal either. I do not want this to happen. What can I do for this?

What do you mean with "Rviz does not work correctly"? Do you mean that it can't display sensor data? What is connected to the Arduino board and what it should do?

Yes, the sensor data is not display. "Robot model" gives an error. I use it to provide control on the PCB. I am trying to get the data from the LED control and distance sensor from the Arduino via topics. I need to get this data. It is connected to the Arduino board via the USB port with the Jetson board. The relevant pins of the Arduino are also connected to the distance sensor and LEDs via the PCB board.

How are you connecting the arduino to ROS? It could be maybe that the PCB create some noise on the serial signal and so the jetson can't read the serial data?
I had experience with a similar problem in the past
